# How to fix sonar issue "Update or refactor this function so that its implementation doesn't duplicate the one on line xxx"

Tags: angular, typescript, sonarqube

SonarQube identifies these 4 functions as duplicates in some specific lines:

1. beneficiaires.forEach(beneficiaire => {
2. () => {

Here is my functions:

```
affectPercentageToBeneficiares(beneficiaires: BeneficiaryData[], sum: number) {
    let numberOfBeneficiaresWithEmptyPrecentage = this.getBeneficiaresWithEmptyPercentageNumber(beneficiaires);
    let valueToAffecte = (100.02 - sum) / numberOfBeneficiaresWithEmptyPrecentage;
    beneficiaires.forEach(beneficiaire => {
        if (beneficiaire.percentage == "") {
            valueToAffecte = Math.round(valueToAffecte * 100) / 100;
            beneficiaire.percentage = "" + valueToAffecte;
        }
    })
}

affectPercentageToBeneficiaresInZeroCase(beneficiaires: BeneficiaryData[]) {
    let numberOfBeneficiaresWithEmptyPrecentage = this.getBeneficiaresWithEmptyPercentageNumber(beneficiaires);
    let valueToAffecte = (100) / numberOfBeneficiaresWithEmptyPrecentage;
    beneficiaires.forEach(beneficiaire => {
        if (beneficiaire.percentage == "") {
            valueToAffecte = Math.round(valueToAffecte * 100) / 100;
            beneficiaire.percentage = "" + valueToAffecte;
        }
    });
}

this.userProfilService.updateUser(this.UpdatedUser)
    .subscribe(
        () => {
            this.toastr.success('User has been updated successfully', null, {
                enableHtml: true,
            });
        },
        (err) => {
            this.toastr.error('erreur dans la modification utilisateur', null, {
                enableHtml: true,
            });
        }
    );

this.userProfilService.addUser(this.User)
    .subscribe(
        () => {
            this.toastr.success('User has been created', null, {
                enableHtml: true,
            });
        },
        (err) => {
            throw err;
        }
    );
```

is there a solution to fix the problem for the first two functions without having to merge them into a single one?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to merge the functions, the problem is that you have exactly the same function in two places (the `forEach` callback). Put that update of beneficiaries into its own function or method, and call that from both places:

```
// Outside the class
function updateBeneficiaires(beneficiaires, valueToAffecte) {
    beneficiaires.forEach(beneficiaire => {
        if (beneficiaire.percentage == "") {
            valueToAffecte = Math.round(valueToAffecte * 100) / 100;
            beneficiaire.percentage = "" + valueToAffecte;
        }
    });
}

// In the class
affectPercentageToBeneficiares(beneficiaires: BeneficiaryData[], sum: number) {
    let numberOfBeneficiaresWithEmptyPrecentage = this.getBeneficiaresWithEmptyPercentageNumber(beneficiaires);
    let valueToAffecte = (100.02 - sum) / numberOfBeneficiaresWithEmptyPrecentage;
    updateBeneficiaires(beneficiaires, valueToAffecte);
}

affectPercentageToBeneficiaresInZeroCase(beneficiaires: BeneficiaryData[]) {
    let numberOfBeneficiaresWithEmptyPrecentage = this.getBeneficiaresWithEmptyPercentageNumber(beneficiaires);
    let valueToAffecte = (100) / numberOfBeneficiaresWithEmptyPrecentage;
    updateBeneficiaires(beneficiaires, valueToAffecte);
}
```

*(Or make it a class method, but it doesn't use any class state so perhaps a private static.)*